# Product Sets as objects in the category $\mathbf{Sets}$, the product category, and final objects

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, products

I am slowly realizing that my understanding of category theory is shaky. Thus, I have the two following (very basic) question.

> In the category $\mathbf{Sets}$, is $A \times B$ an object of the category, with $A$ and $B$ actually objects of the category (i.e., sets)?

It seems to me the alternative would be to explicitly introduce a product category $\mathbf{Sets} \times \mathbf{Sets}$, whose objects are of the form $A \times B$, with $A$ and $B$ sets.

(Small aside, if $A \times B$ is indeed an object of $\mathbf{Sets}$, its relation to the final object $\mathbf{1}$ in $\mathbf{Sets}$ (a singleton set) provided by $! : A \times B \to \mathbf{1}$ is as expected?)

I have the feeling the answer to my question is positive and it is related to the fact that $\mathbf{Sets}$ is a Cartesian closed category (which should also cover the finality issue, I think), but I am not really sure.

Thanks a lot for your feedback and your time!

Comment: Yes, the cartesian product $A \times B$ is another set, so it's another object of the category. There is also an "external product" living in $\text{Set} \times \text{Set}$ which is more precisely the ordered pair $(A, B)$. The cartesian product has a homomorphism to $1$ but so does every other object, it's not special in that way. None of this requires cartesian closure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment (and sorry for my late answer). May I ask you something, which maybe would lead to a full-fledge answer, and that I feel is related to my original question? What do you mean by referring to the other "external product"? Or, maybe better, in which way the two are different? Is it that the projection operator has to properly "live" where the external product lives? (Sorry, I am not sure it makes sense what I just wrote.)

Comment: I don't actually know if "external product" is the right name; I used it by analogy with an operation called the external tensor product but it's a bit less analogous than I thought it was. Anyway, regardless of what it's called, it's a different operation from the product because it produces an object in a different category. I'm not sure what to say other than that. The projection $A \times B \to A$ can be thought of as a morphism in $\text{Set}$ from the product; there is also a projection *functor* $\text{Set} \times \text{Set} \to \text{Set}$, which is *not* a morphism.

Comment: Thanks a lot: your last sentence was most useful!